# .htaccess - Rewrite with multiple parameters not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I am creating a rule to display addresses of type :

```
main.php?cat=MyCategory
main.php?cat=MyCategory&sub=MySubcategory
main.php?cat=MyCategory&sub=MySubcategory&prod=MyProduct
```

As

```
MyDomain.com/MyCategory
MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory
MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory/MyProduct
```

but there are two problems:

The first problem is that the other links on the displayed page start in the wrong position.

```
MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory/MyProduct/newlink.html
```

should be referenced to the root, like this

```
MyDomain.com/newlink.html
```

Second problem is that from 2nd/3rd URL levels, my references such as javascript, img src and css links are wrong. It looks for these files relative from the up levels url. How do I fix this?

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1&sub=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&prod=$3  [L]
```

Tried with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newlink\.html$
```

But not working, any ideas?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Do you have more than .htaccess in your system?

Comment: htaccess is located in root dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first query to deal with 4th level .html format URLs try following .htaccess rules file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/)([^.]*\.html)/?$  $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1&sub=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&prod=$3  [L]
```

***For JS/CS rewrite/redirect:***
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: @Jam, Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: I still have the problem of access from the different levels.
I have the URL like this:

MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory/MyProduct/newlink.html

It should be like this:
MyDomain.com/newlink.html

Comment: @Jam, Could you please do elaborate on this one, what's not working, thank you.

Comment: Sure, when I reach the higher levels, everithing is fine e.g. 

MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory
or 
MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory/MyProduct

But if inside these pages, I try to access to 

MyDomain.com/newlink.html

I get these results: 

MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory/MyProduct/newlink.html 
or
MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory/newlink.html
or
MyDomain.com/MyCategory/newlink.html 

which is incorrect

Comment: @Jam, ok so when you hit link `MyDomain.com/newlink.html` what redirection you are expecting in browser?

Comment: I espect to go to MyDomain.com/newlink.html.  Actually goes to MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory/MyProduct/newlink.html or MyDomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategory/newlink.html or MyDomain.com/MyCategory/newlink.html

Comment: @Jam, Where is your newlink.html present in server actually?

Comment: @Jam: Looks like, you still don't have `<base href="/">` included in your page HTML's `head` section.

Comment: @Jam, Kindly try anubhava sir's suggestion which is there in my answer also and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: I've added Base href="/" and now is fine.   Thanks¡

Comment: @Jam, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.